# SensorEventListener temporarily not working

Tags: android

I've implemented SensorEventListener in my MainActivity, and it works quite well, i'd even say *most of the time* very well.

But weirdly, sometimes it completely stops working, I need to shake it in every direction for 5-10 seconds and it's magically back on.
It seems to be after the phone as idle/asleep for a long time.

I did implemented the register/unregister on onResume/onPause.

Here is my code, mostly coming from stackoverflow:

```
SensorManager sensorManager;

private float accel; // acceleration apart from gravity
private float accelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
private float accelLast; // last acceleration including gravity
private static final float SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 12.f;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initSensor();
}


private void initSensor() {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    registerSensor();
}

private void registerSensor() {
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_NAME_SENSOR);
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, handler);
    accel = 0.00f;
    accelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    accelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerSensor();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    accelLast = accelCurrent;
    accelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
    float delta = accelCurrent - accelLast;
    accel = accel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
    //Log.d(TAG, ">>> ALL shake accel = "+ accel);
    if (accel > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
        Log.d(TAG, "shake accel = "+ accel);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do stuffs in the UI
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Nothing do to here
}
```

Comment: You unregister your listener in `onPause` which will probably be called when your phone goes to sleep and you only register it in `onCreate`. If your activity is visible when your phone goes to sleep, it is not created when you wake the phone up. Instead it is resume (trough `onResume`) and I think you should register your listener again in that callback

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. Though you can see in my code that I did implemented the onResume were I re-register the sensor.

Comment: I probably wasn't paying attention when I was typing my comment, because I completely missed that. Sorry!

Comment: No problem ;-).
It's really strange to be honest. It doesn't work for like 10 seconds then starts again with nothing special happening. The phone is on during the whole process, no Pause / Resume happening at the moment it starts working again. I just wait, and it's back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by changing the sensor delay to SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST;
The registration now looks like :

```
// Global
private static final String HANDLER_THREAD_NAME_SENSOR = "sensorThread";

// ...Registration
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_NAME_SENSOR);
handlerThread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                    mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST,
                    handler);
```